# How to set DNS to WiFi router modem internet

Tags: router, internet, dns, modem, broadband

I am using a WiFi modem to connect to internet. It is a router AWA a modem (Teracom Wireless Wifi Router cum ADSL2 + Modem).

[image: ADSL Modem Image]

The connection is secure. I have a broadband connection, which requires username and password. The connection settings are not set inside the modem (and I don't want to) so that each time, after my laptop connect to the modem through WiFi, I manually dial broadband connection. These all works fine.

But I want to change DND server settings, since the default settings blocks access to some websites. I downloaded DNS jumper software. Using that, I can successfully change DNS of my

1. Bluetooth device PAN
2. Broadcom Netlink Gigabit Ethernet and
3. Intel WiFi Link 5100 AGN.

But there is another entry in the drop-down list, that is the name of my broadband connection (that I dial using un and pw). But each time I change the DNS of this entry, it is getting restored. I cant change that entry.

So which DNS address should I change to access those blocked sites and (or) to improve speed? and why cant I change the broadband connection's DNS?

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

Right click on the Broadband Connection

Left click on Properties

Left click on Networking

Left click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

Left click on Properties

Select Use the following DNS server addresses

In Preferred DNS server: enter 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS server).

Left click OK

Left click OK

Connect